# Extend pandas dataframe entries to same length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

data_df = df(data={"Number": [234, 7892, 109736, 8384664088]})

print(data_df)

       Number
0         234
1        7892
2      109736
3  8384664088
```

How can I quickly extend the entries in the dataframe to be the length of the entry with the maximum length using a particular character? For example, if I use "#" to extend them to something like:

```
       Number
0  234#######
1  7892######
2  109736####
3  8384664088
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the max width with [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and then use [`str.pad`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html) to pad each entry:

```
max_width = data_df['Number'].astype(str).str.len().max()
data_df['Number'].astype(str).str.pad(side='right', fillchar='#', width=max_width)
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be using [`str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html) to fill the right side of the numbers cast to string with as many `#` as needed to reach the maximum length:

```
max_len = len(str(max(data_df.Number)))
data_df['Number'] = data_df.Number.astype(str).str.ljust(max_len, '#')

    Number
0  234#######
1  7892######
2  109736####
3  8384664088
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the length of max number from the column and append `#`

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

data_df = df(data={"Number": [234, 7892, 109736, 8384664088]})

n = len(str(data_df['Number'].max()))

data_df['Number'] = [str(i)+'#'*(n-len(str(i))) for i in data_df['Number']]
print(data_df)
```

Output:

```
      Number                                                                                                                         
0  234#######                                                                                                                         
1  7892######                                                                                                                         
2  109736####                                                                                                                         
3  8384664088
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
lng = len(str(max(data_df.Number)))
data_df['Number'] = data_df['Number'].map(lambda x: f'{x:#<lng}')

       Number
0  234#######
1  7892######
2  109736####
3  8384664088
```